# How to extract information from GetCompletedEventargs

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I am using `WCF` to interact to my `DB`, execute a `stored procedure` which returns a single row(ID,prodName,Details).

**Service.svn.cs**

```
public List<Product> GetProducts(string productName,int productCode)
{
  ProductDataClassDataContext db = new ProductDataClassDataContext();
  var products = db.usp_Get_Product(productName,productCode); //calling stored procedure that returns a single row (ID,prodName,Details)
  return products.ToList();
}
```

From what I understand, the rows are returned in `ServiceReference1.GetProductsCompletedEventArgs e` which is binded to my `DataGrid` via the result property `e.Result`.

```
public void webService_GetProductsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetProductsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  ProductGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;
  lblText.Text = // set it to the value of column prodName 
}
```

My question is, how can I extract the value of column `prodName`? Is it available in `e.Result`? If yes how can I set `lblText.Text to it? Any property? Please help

Comment: You need to show how these two bits of code relate. There's no event handler creation or obvious relationship between `ProductDataClassDataContext` and handler.

Comment: Yes, it is available in `e.Result`. Just do this: `lblText.Content = e.Result[index].prodName;` , where `index` is 0,1,2,3.... depending on how many `Product` were returned in `e.Result` and which one you want to assign to `lblText`.